# Using Solrj (querying and indexing)

Tags: java, curl, solr, solrj, solrcloud

eWorking on a Natural language processing project using Solr.

I am a complete amateur in relation to Solr, So keep that in mind please. I started a solr server using cmd:

```
 Solr.cmd Start -e techproducts
```

then I tried querying using SolrJ

```
public class SolrJ {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SolrServerException, IOException {
    SolrClient client = new Builder("http://localhost:8983/solr/#").build();
        QueryResponse response = client.query(new SolrQuery("*:*"));
    SolrDocumentList results = response.getResults();
    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i) {
        System.out.println(results.get(i));
    }
}
}
```

When run it I got:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/#: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html.

Note that this query worked when I tried it with a two cluster server (as shown in "http://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/solr-tutorial.html"

can someone please explain the difference between

```
Solr.cmd -e cloud
```

and

```
solr.cmd -e techproducts
```

Why does only cloud have collections?

Also, I am struggling to override the `SolrConfig.xml` file using an API, can someone please explain the steps needed to create an API for overriding `SolrConfig.xml`. I tried using curl commands to do so from cmd, but I think that is a wrong approach. config API is accessible through http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/config 
but how do I use it?

I apologize for the incoherence, this is the first time I am posting anything on Stack Overflow.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try removing the char # from the Solr url and please try again with http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts

Comment: I was about to say that doesn't work, but it did. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain why is it without the # when querying but with it when accessing from the admin?

Comment: A `#` is a local anchor - it's only used by the browser - it should never be transferred to the server. If your client actually escapes the `#` and sends it to the server, the server doesn't understand what's happening (i.e. the server have no resource named `#`, as this is never sent to the server by the browser). See [Fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).

Comment: Thanks! As for the request handler that i want to develop to interact with SolrConfig, are you familiar with SolrJ commands? If so, could you please explain how do I send a request to override the SolrConfig from SolrJ? If not, I would love a short explanation on the Config API.Every command that is longer than 1 line in cmd didn't work and was considered by the cmd as seperate commands.